# Same method that could return 3 different types depending on REST call's result

Tags: java, oop

I have a function that will:

1. make a REST call to an endpoint. The endpoint might return a String, Integer or Boolean depending on the field I want to query the endpoint for.
2. accordingly, we will cast the result to String/ Boolean/ Integer to be returned from the function.

The simplified version of the function is similar to this:

```
private Boolean getFlag (String argument) {
   Object [][] code = restConnector.getCodes(argument);
   return (Boolean) code[0][0]
}
```

Except for the return type, the code for the function is the same.

The simple way will be to have 3 functions, each have different return type, but this means a lot of boilerplate code (because except for return type, everything else is the same for 3 functions).

I am wondering if there is a better way to design the code so that I only have 1 function / the boilerplate code could be minimal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would this 1 function determine which return type to use?

Comment: Will you already know which type to cast to, at the call site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Generics for this. Here is a link to a good dokumentation:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

```java
private <T> T getFlag(String argument, Class<T> returnType) {
Object[][] code = restConnector.getCodes(argument);
return returnType.cast(code[0][0]);
}
```

With this modification, you can call the function with different return types as follows:

```java
Boolean bool = getFlag("argument", Boolean.class);
String text = getFlag("argument", String.class);
Integer num = getFlag("argument", Integer.class);
```

Comment: thanks. Currently, I already have existing code with > 10 functions that are calling getFlag("argument") and they all return String. 

It's my new code of calling some new arguments that'll return Integer and Boolean. 

Doing what you mentioned means I need to go to all 10 functions and add the return type argument (String) there. May I ask if you think it's a good idea or is there some better way to do it? 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write type-specific methods that call a common method:

```
public boolean getBooleanFlag(String argument) {
   return (boolean) getFlag(argument);
}

public String getStringFlag(String argument) {
   return (String) getFlag(argument);
}

public int getIntFlag(String argument) {
   return (int) getFlag(argument);
}

private Object getFlag(String argument) {
   Object [][] code = restConnector.getCodes(argument);
   return code[0][0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not safe, you can use generics like so:

```
public class Main {
    
    private static Object match(final String argument) {
        if ("boolean".equals(argument))
            return true;
        if ("integer".equals(argument))
            return 0;
        if ("string".equals(argument))
            return "str";
        return null;
    }
    
    public static <T> T getFlag(final String argument) {
        final Object[][] code = new Object[][]{new Object[]{ match(argument) }}; //restConnector.getCodes(argument);
        return (T) code[0][0];
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Boolean booleanFlag = getFlag("boolean");
        final int integerFlag = getFlag("integer");
        final String stringFlag = getFlag("string");
        final Object randomFlag = getFlag("random");
        System.out.println("Boolean: " + booleanFlag);
        System.out.println("Integer: " + integerFlag);
        System.out.println("String:  " + stringFlag);
        System.out.println("Random:  " + randomFlag);
    }
}
```

prints:

> Boolean: true
> Integer: 0
> String:  str
> Random:  null

But when the type cannot be inferred, then it will not work. For example the following is a compilation error:

```
System.out.println(getFlag("any"));
```

This is because `println` is overloaded (accepts different types).

Note that with this method, you are also running the risk of a `java.lang.ClassCastException` if you don't known what type your `getCodes` will return. Take for example the following code:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static <T> T getFlag(final String argument) {
        final Object[][] code = new Object[][]{new Object[]{"Always a string!"}}; //restConnector.getCodes(argument);
        return (T) code[0][0];
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Boolean booleanFlag = getFlag("boolean");
        final int integerFlag = getFlag("integer");
        final String stringFlag = getFlag("string");
        final Object randomFlag = getFlag("random");
        System.out.println("Boolean: " + booleanFlag);
        System.out.println("Integer: " + integerFlag);
        System.out.println("String:  " + stringFlag);
        System.out.println("Random:  " + randomFlag);
    }
}
```

... which throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException` in the first call.

Finally note that you are also running the risk of a `java.lang.NullPointerException` if you don't known if your `getCodes` will return `null`. Replace for example `"Always a string!"` with `null` in the above code, and you will get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the *second* call.